# Disabling post_type in URL

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, rewrite-rules

I noticed that by default, WordPress lists all posts if you use mysite.com/**?post_type=post** at the end of the URL.

What's the simplest way of deactivating this? I would prefer it redirected to my 404 page.

Answer (score 2):

I *think* you might be able to accomplish this via filter.  Looking at the core `wp` class you'll find the `$public_query_vars` and `$private_query_vars`variables defined by a hardcoded array.  These could probably be overriden/changed via the global `$wp` object but if you dig a bit deeper there's a filter that should let you remove items from the public array only when parsing a request.  here's the code and docs from core:

```
/**
         * Filters the query variables whitelist before processing.
         *
         * Allows (publicly allowed) query vars to be added, removed, or changed prior
         * to executing the query. Needed to allow custom rewrite rules using your own arguments
         * to work, or any other custom query variables you want to be publicly available.
         *
         * @since 1.5.0
         *
         * @param array $public_query_vars The array of whitelisted query variables.
         */
        $this->public_query_vars = apply_filters( 'query_vars', $this->public_query_vars );
```

That is in `parse_request()` so removing the offending vars from the array at that point should stop that querystring from working, without breaking anything. Keep in mind thought hat I haven't tested any of that theory and I may well be entirely off base here.  Good luck!

If that either doesn't work or isn't how you want to handle this then you'll need to use .htaccess redirects to accomplish this.

Comment: That sort of works, I removed post_type from public_query_vars on line 18 in class-wp.php and it loads the home page but doesn't redirect to it. I experimented with all the other items in the array eg 'm' and noticed the same thing happens if you go mysite.com/?m=post. Can I remove the whole array without breaking it? I'd prefer to just work off the theme though and I'm surprised this isn't a settings option in Wordpress

Comment: You could try `add_filter('query_vars', function($vars){return []})`. That might do it.  I would definitely recommend to not edit anything in core files as that makes your site unable to take any updates.  And double check that code for syntax errors, I'm typing this on my phone.

Comment: Alas, that does not work from the theme. Another hack I've figured is to modify the index.php to not display any posts.

Comment: So now my index.php file looks like `<?php 
wp_redirect(home_url());
exit;
?>` which seems to do the trick.